# Определить есть ли три подряд стоящих одинаковых символа в строке

Tags: python

Вводится строка, если в ней есть 3 подряд стоящих одинаковых символа, то надо вывести NO, если нет - YES

Comment: Регулярочки? Или кто подскажет красивое решение на Монти?

Comment: Не понял оба вопроса.

Comment: Странный цикл какой-то нужно так:  

    for k in range( 0, len(str)-3 ):
        if same3( str[k:k+3] ):
        ...

Или регулярка:  

     (.)\1{2}

Если не более трех подряд:  

    (.)\1{2}(?!\1)

Comment: ReinRaus, спасибо, использовал Ваш цикл, все почти хорошо, за исключением того, что если в строке три подряд символа идут после более 3х разных, то выводит несколько раз YES и один раз NO. Как исправить эту ошибку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Регулярные выражения спешат на помощь!

```
import re

str1 = 'qwerty'
str2 = 'qwerttty'

regex = re.compile(r'^.*(.)(\1)(\1).*$')

print 'YES' if regex.match(str1) else 'NO'
print 'YES' if regex.match(str2) else 'NO'
```

А ваша программа не работает потому что в срезе, который вы берёте на каждой итерации всего 2 элемента.

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> i = 2
>>> j = 0
>>> s[j:i]
[1, 2]
```

*Ну, или как-то так:*

```
same3 = lambda s: min([len(x) for x in [set(x) for x in [s[x:x+3] for x in range(len(s) - 2)]]]) == 1

same3('qwerty')    // False
same3('qwerttty')  // True
```

*Да! Я сделал это! Я написал программу, менее читабельную, чем регулярка, которой она эквивалентна!*

А если серьёзно, эта программа делает следующее:

```
s = 'qwerty'

triplets = [s[x:x+3] for x in range(len(s) - 2)]
// находим все тройки подряд идущих символов
// для `qwerty` получим ['qwe', 'wer', 'ert', 'rty']

sets = [set(x) for x in triplets]
// каждую тройку преобразуем в множество (set)
// особенность множества - в нём нет повторяющихся элементов

lengths = [len(x) for x in sets]
// вычисляем размер каждого множества
// если размер какого-либо множества равен 1, то все элементы, входящие в него, равны

minlen = min(lengths)
// находим множество минимальной длины

print minlen == 1
```

Ну, и объявление функции `same3 = lambda s: ...` эквивалентно классическому:

```
def same3(s):
    ...
```

Comment: С такой регулярной строка, содержащая более 3 одинаковых букв в ряд "qwqrtttttttqff" тоже будет засчитана. Можно ли изменить это поведение силами рег. выражений?

Comment: @moron: Любая строка, содержащая 4 одиноковых букв в ряд, также содержит 3 одинаковых буквы подряд. Если изменить условие и потребовать, чтобы **ровно** 3 подряд стоящих одинаковых символа шло, то это также можно сделать с помощью рег. выр.: [`(.)(?<!\1.)\1{2}(?!\1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10320338/4279)

Answer (score 0):

> Вводится строка, если в ней есть 3
> подряд стоящих одинаковых символа, то
> надо вывести NO, если нет - YES

```
import re

print("NO" if re.search(r"(.)" + r"\1" * (3 - 1), s) else "YES")
```

Или без регулярных выражений:

```
from itertools import groupby

print("NO" if any(len(list(dups)) > (3 - 1) for _, dups in groupby(s)) else "YES")
```